# Is Github Package Registry an alternative to Docker registry?

Tags: github, artifactory, docker-registry

Github just announced its own package registry and loads of articles on the Web, like for instance [this one](https://www.google.com/amp/s/techcrunch.com/2019/05/10/github-gets-a-package-registry/amp/), mention that:

> To be clear, GitHub isn’t launching a competitor to tools like npm or
>   RubyGems. What the company is launching, however, is a service that is
>   compatible with these tools and allows developers to find and publish
>   their own packages, using the same GitHub interface they use for their
>   code. The new service is currently compatible with JavaScript (npm),
>   Java (Maven), Ruby (RubyGems), .NET (NuGet) and Docker images, with
>   support for other languages and tools to come.

Even after reading the features [here](https://github.com/features/package-registry?utm_campaign=1557509318&utm_medium=social&utm_source=linkedin&utm_content=1557509318), I am not completely clear about a couple of things.

- If the beta is successful won't Github be an alternative to Docker registry and  a competitor for Docker for
  instance?
- Also how will github registry be positioned in respect of
  artifactory?